# IdentityServer4 professional deployment with https on IIS 8.5

Tags: ssl, iis, https, identityserver4, .net-core-2.0

Context :
I'm working on a IdentityServer4 evolution with a special scope management.

I started from the sample 
**Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage** available at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage works well with addresses localhost:5000 for identity server, 5001 for API and 5002 for MVC Client.

I created 3 sub domains for my demo domain.

I created 3 Let's encrypt SHA certificates for my subdomains.

I installed all IIS Security option (including IIS Client certificat Mapping and client certificat mapping).

I configured each subdomain to run properly with https (it works).

Issue :
When I launch the MVCClient app, and I try to go to secure page I have this error :

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://authorize.mydomain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever+d__8.MoveNext()

InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://authorize.mydomain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager+d__24.MoveNext()

I know it's a IIS configuration issue and not a source code issue.

A lot of discussions talk abour this error but only for IIS Express or for localhost addresses.

Do you have an idea to make this working ?

Comment: Just directly ... are you able to view the well known endpoint ?

Comment: I found my error. I generated database and initializing data BEFORE setting up https. So encrypted parts of the database was done with the wrong key.

Solution is to seed database after setting up all https with certificates.